# Rspec spec failing -- undefined method `permissions' for RSpec::ExampleGroups::UserPolicy:Class (NoMethodError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, pundit

I'm installing an app with Pundit authorization and when I try to run RSpec tests I get:

```
undefined method `permissions'
  for RSpec::ExampleGroups::UserPolicy:Class
      (NoMethodError)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found out what the problem was...

Following line in `rails_helper.rb` was commented out:

```
# The following line is provided for convenience purposes. It has the downside
# of increasing the boot-up time by auto-requiring all files in the support
# directory. Alternatively, in the individual `*_spec.rb` files, manually
# require only the support files necessary.
#
Dir[Rails.root.join("spec/support/**/*.rb")].each { |f| require f }
```

Activating it made the tests work correctly :)

Answer (score 14):

Also remember to add this your **rails_helper**

```
require 'pundit/rspec'
```

Comment: My tests were failing with this error when I started using `parallel_tests`. This `require` on `rails_helper` solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

I **had** `require 'pundit/rspec'` but I had misspelt "policies" in the spec directory structure:

`spec/polices/my_policy_spec.rb`

My mistake also returned the permission error message.

You can fix it by spelling policies correctly, alternatively, set the type of the test file to policy.

```
RSpec.describe MyPolicy, type: :policy do
  ...
  ...
end
```